# How to highlight one or more cells of a row on datagrid rowload in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following code attached to the row load event on my datagrid :

```
private void myGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject o = e.Row.DataContext as MyObject;
    string highlightColour = ...;

    if (o.Source == "...")
        e.Row.Background = ...;
    else
        e.Row.Background = null;
}
```

The issue is I am in need of highlighting some cells in the row and not others instead of the whole row, how do I go about acheiving that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as below

Assume you need to change cell index 1 and 2

```
 e.Row.Cells[1].Background  = ....
 e.Row.Cells[2].Background  = ....
```

Comment: Hmm, if only it was that easy. I dont have access to the .Cells collection in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

If you`re ok with XAML solution then you can use CellStyle for this:

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyProperty, 
                                               Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Where `MyProperty` is your objects property you need to check and `myConverter` is a IValueConverter that returns some `Brush` based on your logic.
This example is just for one column but you can move this style to resources and use in every column that needs that functionality.